# Variation on Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (disjoint discs)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curvature

In lecture the other day we were talking about the (local) Gauss-Bonnet Theorem: Which states: $$\int_{U} K \cdot dA + \int_{0}^{L} \kappa_{g} \cdot dt = 2\pi$$ where K is the Gauss Curvature of the manifold and $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature. This is for a manifold, U, which is diffeomorphic to a closed disc with a smooth boundary.

---

The variation is as follows:

Now imagine $V$ is diffeomorphic to a closed disc. Let $U = V - \cup_{i=1}^{k} D_{i}$ where $D_{i} \subset V$ are disjoint open discs. What would the Guass Bonnet formula for U be?

---

So what's being added here is "boundaries" on the inside of the manifold, k of them to be specific, which don't overlap (as they are disjoint) tus we may assume each one traces out an entire disc unimpeded. Could we then say each disc contributes 2$\pi$ and thus we would modify our GB equation by changing the RHS from $2\pi$ to $2k\pi$? That seems really simplistic though.. I saw something about a global version with the Euler Characteristic $\chi$ = $2 - 2g$ where $g$ is the "genus" or "number of handles" could this be the solution?

Comment: If the surface has a single "handle", i.e. $M \cong$ a torus...this is not the same as having something homeomorphic to an open disk being cut out of, say, a sphere.  In particular, a torus has no boundary, whereas a sphere with a hole punched in it would.  Globally speaking, if the surface has no boundary, then we'll have $2 \pi \chi(M) = \displaystyle \int_M K \ dA$.  If instead a boundary does exist (as it would if we punched out a disk), then a term is added to the RHS of the above equality: $\displaystyle \int_{\partial M} k_g \ ds$.

Comment: I see, which makes sense.. but what about adding disjoint discs to the inside of the boundary? We are still keeping the original boundary and thus both terms on RHS of your equality remain but does the Euler Characteristic basically cover the addition of k disjoint discs in he equation or do I need to add something else?

Comment: I am rusty on my differential geometry, but I believe it would, yes.  Careful though: punching out those disks *adds* to the original boundary.  But if you triangulate the surface and compute the Euler characteristic -- even if disks have been removed from the surface -- you'll still end up with $2 \pi \chi(M)$ equaling whatever the sum of integrals would be on the RHS.  However, punching out a disk could very well change the Euler characteristic relative to what it was before punching it out (notice a disk is not homeomorphic to an annulus).

Comment: Right, @KajHansen and Kyle. Each time you remove an (open) disk, you add a circle to the boundary and the Euler characteristic goes down by $1$. (There are fancier ways to see this, but if you think in terms of triangulations, you're removing one face when you remove that open disk.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The genus is only defined for surfaces without boundary, but the Euler characteristic does exactly what you think it does (except it's half what you've described). You can define a triangulation for your surface (some triangles will have curved sides), then count the number $V$ of vertices, plus the number $F$ of faces, minus the number $E$ of edges. The difference $\chi:=V+F-E$ is the Euler characteristic. This is a topological invariant (the same for any two homeomorphic regions), and it's equal to 1 for a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, imagine you have some such triangulation, and you remove $k$ non-adjacent, interior triangles. The Euler characteristic decreases by $k$, since $F$ decreases by $k$ and $V$ and $E$ are unchanged. Thus, a region with $k$ holes has Euler characteristic $\chi=1-k$. Your disc with discs removed is homeomorphic to this region, so it also has Euler characteristic $\chi=1-k$. Then the Gauss-Bonnet theorem (see e.g. Chavel's *Riemannian Geometry: A Modern Introduction*, Theorem V.2.7) states

$$\int_{\partial M} \kappa\, ds + \iint_M \mathcal{K} \,dA = 2\pi \chi.$$